# Is This User a Spammer?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, spam

Most of the answers of [user424257](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424257/user424257) are to questions about FTP. This user almost always recommends the WebDAV products of this company: http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/.

I have suggested in comments that the user tell us why he should not be considered a spammer. Today he replied:

> @John Saunders: It is obvious that
>   WebDAV and FTP are related
>   technologies. If you need an
>   explanation why "WebDAV is much more
>   modern and feature-rich" here is it:
>   stackoverflow.com/questions/3714363/webdav-vs-ftp-sftp-ftps
>   – user424257

I do not consider this to be an adequate defense. What does everyone else think?

Comment: I love it. He answered your accusation of spamming with a marketing message. Spam is as spam does.

Comment: Spaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaam!

Comment: Perhaps unrelated: I got three downvotes within a minute of each other; four within ten minutes, About the number of times I downvoted this user.

Comment: Link to the answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626597/how-to-build-a-ftp-server/3706455#3706455

Comment: At the current moment, in the 10k rep Tools, Flags section on SO, 15 of this user's answers are flagged as spam, several by multiple people.  That's out of the 30 currently flagged answers.

Comment: Nuke him from orbit, it's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Just hardcode any request to post containing `webdav` with impossible captcha puzzles and make his downvotes work in reverse.

Comment: See also: [Limit to self-promotion in answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limit-to-self-promotion-in-answers), [Vendors on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20031/vendors-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is a meat puppet for Eugene Mayevski, a notorious spammer for Eldos.  You can see them both at work in this [fake question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714363/webdav-vs-ftp-sftp-ftps).  The connection is a bit complicated, but Eldos seems to be a US marketing front for a company from the Ukraine, called SoftPanorama++.  This webdavsystem.com URL is also owned by a company from the Ukraine.  My Cyrillic isn't quite good enough to decode the web page, but both look to be based in Kiev and offers the same products.  Heck of a coincidence.

Mayevski has been featured prominently in moderator tools "flags" section for the past year.  That this pita hasn't been banned yet is one of my life's little mysteries.  I gave up flagging the mods on him a while ago.

Comment: There's some conflicting evidence; his answer to [Cross-platform solution for mounting a custom filesystem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235286/cross-platform-solution-for-mounting-a-custom-filesystem/3647801#3647801) recommends (obviously) the same product, but it's in response to a question that actually suggests an Eldos product as a possible solution.  If he is a spammer for Eldos, why wouldn't he pick that one?

Comment: @Aarobot: I'm only really sure that Mayevski is a spammer for Eldos.  For all I know, this is a Ukranian maffia operation headquartered in Kiev.  What's the term for a sock puppet on the left hand?  Meat puppet or something?

Comment: Oops, no, that would be right hand.  Ahem, hated that image flash there.

Comment: My "Cyrillic" (if that's how you call everything that looks like Russian) is good enough to tell that SoftPanorama and webdavsystem are located at different places in Kiev (which is a big city) and look like they're different companies.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a sock puppet, from what I can tell.

Comment: @mmyers: I guess that's why he suggested a meat puppet after I posted my comment.  Might be a different person but recruited as a shill.  Or might not be.  I don't think it really matters *who* he's spamming for; spam is spam.

Answer (score 13):

I think it's pretty clear that he's a spammer.  40 answers and *every single one* of them has that link.  (OK, I just did a spot check, but I was 10 for 10).

Even if he was just throwing this link into every single WebDAV question, I would still consider him a spammer; the fact that he's also spamming it in FTP questions should eliminate any reasonable doubt.

<sub>He's even posting that link in questions about *virtual drives*.  Hey, our miracle product will also cook your bacon and waffles in the morning for you!</sub>

Comment: Will a unicorn be serving me the bacon and waffles?

Comment: @rchern: are you implying that there are circumstances under which one should *decline* bacon and waffles?

Comment: @rchern: Unicorns aren't actually real, but if you like, I can tape an ice cream cone to a pony's head for you.

Comment: @Aarobot - If unicorns aren't real, then neither are rainbows, glitter and happy thoughts.

Comment: There are quite allot of different links, and most are relevant to the question answered. Majority of the links extend the answer or give more information about solution. Many links has nothing to do with a particular product, but describe how to solve an issue. Here is an example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543000/questions-regarding-the-command-net-use-http-myserver-com/3566137#3566137

Comment: @Jon: None of those are real to me.  Especially happy thoughts.

Comment: @user: And even *that* one somehow manages to link to your software, even if it's just a support page.  Have you posted even *one single* answer that didn't link to that site?

Comment: @Aarobot, Unicorns aren't real?!?!  Is the sky falling too? ):

Comment: @user151320:  Sorry, that's not a particularly good answer.  A commercial link is not an answer to a general question about security implications.

Answer (score 1):

Having many links on SO to his website will increase its search engine popularity a lot.

We should set a limit, for exemple maximum 10% of the answer of a user should contains a link that contains the same domain name, and that is not a domain popular on SO (for exemple MSDN, Google, Microsoft, etc).

Comment: Links on SO are automatically nofollowed, so no search engine juice for him.

Comment: @mmyers, does this apply to MSO as well? Jeff has advised us to not link to clones; for an example, see the comments to [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60297/weask-us-is-cloning-stack-overflow-content/62998#62998).

Comment: @Popular Demand: Yes, I'm not sure if Jeff was actually referring to linking *from MSO* in that comment (and I'm assuming here that I know exactly what `rel="nofollow"` does, which is not necessarily true). View source on this page and you'll see that the webdav link in the question is nofollowed.

Comment: @mmyers, correct you are. Regarding `nofollow`, see this: http://www.webmasterworld.com/google/3183070.htm

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is 'spam' per se.  I think you all are being too quick to judge.

None of the answers seem wrong.  I would recommend just telling him to slow down a bit, and to make sure to disclose any affiliation that he has with the product he is advertising.

Comment: @jinguy: i asked him to explain. His response is above, in my question. I also pointed him to this discussion.

Comment: Actually, several of his answers *do* seem wrong and have nothing to do with the question at hand.  Take, for example, his answer to [Show a DB as a directory (Like Sharepoint Does)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2878832/3566277#3566277).  And most of his answers are blatant copy-paste; compare [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540267/3647818#3647818) to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235286/3647801#3647801) - notice any similarities?

Comment: Many of his answers to questions like "how do I [x] with FTP" are "Use webdav instead". Those are bad answers. That's like saying "How do I connect to MS SQL in C#"... "Use MySQL instead".

Comment: @Jon B:  I disagree that that form of answer is always bad, but it certainly can be.

Comment: @Aarobot: actually all 3 answers that you mention are correct and relevant. The last 2 represent an alternative approach to achieving same result. For example in the second post the user asked about "easy way", the solution recommended is really easier comparing to driver development.

Comment: @David - if the question boils down to "How do I do what jquery is good at by writing code from scratch" and the answer is "use jquery", that's one thing. But suggesting a different technology when the question is about how to do something using FTP is crossing the line.

Comment: @user151320 - um yeah, first of all he didn't ask for an "alternative approach" and secondly you give *no information whatsoever* about how it would actually be accomplished (you just say "buy our stuff").  That's spam.  Don't even try to pretend that you did anything other than search for "webdav" and a few other keywords and blindly copy-paste your crap into every hit you thought *might conceivably* be related.

Comment: I see everyone's point.  However, I still don't think we have enough to condemn him.

Comment: If 40 nearly-identical copy-pasted answers pointing to the same product/web site and zero other activity on the site isn't enough to condemn him then *what **is**!?*

Comment: @Aarobot, well, I fail to see the harm that has been caused.  This isn't link spam, the user is following every other rule on the site.  I just think that they need to be sent an email explaining why they should be more careful.

Comment: *How is this not spam?* He never actually *answers* any of the questions, he just says *"Yeah, our crapware does that, go buy it."*  It's mind-boggling that you're defending this.  What "harm" do you expect to be caused by spam, other than, y'know, *spam*?

Comment: @jjnguy: [from the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion): *"Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation with the product in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product, you're clearly here for the wrong reasons."*

Comment: @user151320: if a question *specifically notes* that Unix/Linux support is a requirement, and you post an answer that *admittedly* won't support *nix, then you have no business claiming to have answered the question.

Comment: @Aarobot: to be fair, he *never* says " **our** crapware". For all we know, he's just such a *huge fan* of said crapware that he feels compelled to crawl the site, looking for any excuse to promote it.

Comment: @Shog9: Exactly.  If he had actually come out and said *our crapware* then at least he wouldn't have run afoul of the disclosure rules.  It would still basically be spam, but it would at least be honest enough that we could say *look, we'll let you promote your crap, but you have to contribute something else too.*

Comment: @aaro, the only reason I'm against any sort of suspension is because I don't feel he has done any thing egregiously wrong.  I'm not rooting for this guy, but I just think that he is entitled to his public defender.

Comment: @Shog, That link to the FAQ is the most relevant piece of literature that has shown that this guy has done something wrong.  However, the only part that's missing from his posts is full disclosure.  That could be fixed fairly easily.

Comment: @Shog9: If you about [this][1] question, you are totally wrong. Literally the "data" the user refers to will become a "part of the machine's file system" on almost any OS, including Linux/Unix and Mac. [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235286/3647801

Comment: @jjnguy: actually, it can't. *HE* could fix it, but *WE* can't know if such a connection exists, nor can we compel him to reveal it if one does, much less say with any confidence that one does not.

Comment: @jinguy:  I understand what you're doing, but I think SO does have an interest in keeping commercial spam off the site, and this is a pretty egregious case.  If we don't suspend repeat spammers on this much evidence, we may as well give up on it.  Are you suggesting that we accept accounts that do nothing except make canned spam answers wherever they might be vaguely relevant and a few other places?  (Anybody but me remember Hasan Mutlu/Serdar Argic/other aliases on Usenet?)

Comment: I'd also like to mention at this point that instead of at least *trying* to cooperate and offering to take steps to remedy the situation like [this user did](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50038/it-doesnt-matter-what-the-question-is-theres-only-one-answer/50066#50066), our new friend here has been stubbornly insisting that he hasn't done anything wrong.  That's not the behaviour of someone who's acting in good faith.

Comment: @David, I think that the first action should be a stern email telling him to stop.  It does appear though that this user doesn't seem to be up for changing his behavior.  In that case, I say suspend.

Comment: @Aarobot, yah, I'm having a hard time defending him now...